# how to send emails from js

Tags: javascript, email

I have been working on website for shopping. I want to add new ability for customers to make their emails and get the verification code in email. I have watched bunch of tutorials but no progress. please help me if you can.

I have watched bunch of tutorials but no progress. please help me if you can.

Comment: Use nodemailer library

Comment: You can use some service that provide API for that.  Maybe https://www.mailgun.com/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use nodemailer
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/use-nodemailer-to-send-emails-from-your-node-js-server/

, or you can use google apps script
https://script.google.com/home/start?pli=1